# Как обновить часть страницы?

Tags: ajax, javascript, wordpress, html

Есть файл с функциями где записано следующее:

```
function myPoll_v_1(){
global $user_ID; if ($user_ID) {//если залогинен то показываем
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#poll-container').load('p/myPoll/xxx.html');//подгружаем форму для голосования
});
</script>
<div id="poll-container">//сюда подгружаем
</div>
<?
    }else{//если незалогинен ничего не показываем
     echo  ' ';
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла ххх.хтмл:

** удалил эти три строчки**

```
<div id="poll-container">
<h3>Poll</h3>
<form id='poll' action="/p/myPoll/poll.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<p>Pick your favorite Javascript framework:</p><p>
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt1" id="opt1" /><label for='opt1'>&nbsp;jQuery</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt2" id="opt2" /><label for='opt2'>&nbsp;Ext JS</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt3" id="opt3" /><label for='opt3'>&nbsp;Dojo</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt4" id="opt4" /><label for='opt4'>&nbsp;Prototype</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt5" id="opt5" /><label for='opt5'>&nbsp;YUI</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt6" id="opt6" /><label for='opt6'>&nbsp;mootools</label><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Vote &rarr;" /></p>
</form>
</div>
```

Функция вызывается в сайд баре вордпресса (из меню виджетов).

В данный момент при нажатии на кнопку, происходит переход на poll.php.
Как сделать так, чтобы перехода не происходило, вся работа осуществлялась в `<div id="poll-container"></div>`

(Что же я пытаюсь сделать? Пытаюсь прикрутить [это голосование](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=832) к вордпрессу.)

**upd**
хм... действительно две строчки там были левые (ссылка на несуществующий джеквери и плагина для него), убрал еще и  poll.js (он ведь прописан в хедере страницы, где должна показываться форма) вернулся опять к тому что было, теперь форма не реагирует ни на что.

**UPD2**
проблема окончательно решена  [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34553)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело наверное `<input type="submit" value="Vote &rarr;" />`, при сабмитте он переходит на обработчик формы, нужно добавить ему `onclick="return false"`, но вы, наверное, что-то неправильно делаете, поскольку в демо перезагрузки нет. Если не можете нормально установить, создайте отдельную хтмл страницу и грузите ее через `iframe` в нужное место - это самый простой и быстрый способ, но конечно лучше разобраться с этим плагином.

Comment: Да. Все разбираюсь. Чувствую, пока не изучу эту всю тему "аякс", не сделаю никакого голосования.

`onclick="return false"` -- не помогло.

(он вроде подгружает данные нормально сначала, но при нажатии выдает результат, но уже на другой странице)

Дело в том, что в примере одна конкретная страница, а я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы у меня на всех страницах висело это голосование.

Всю голову уже сломал.

Comment: так количество страниц не имеет значения, лучше внимательно проверьте все ли вы скрипты подключили, все ли они действительно грузяться, и зачем вы грузите страницу через load, просто вставьте хтмл код в шаблон и подключите нужные файлы в хеад сайта, проверьте все внимательно

Comment: дело в том, что в php файле есть такая строка:

define('HTML_FILE', 'xxx.html');

как сказано в уроке:

"Когда форма будет заполнена и отправлена на обработку, PHP необходимо знать в какой файл записывать результат и соответственно возвращать. Поэтому нам необходимо создать ещё одну константу."

как делать по другому я не знаю. изначально я вставлял код в шаблон, но тогда вообще никаких действий не происходило, даже консоль ничего не выдавала.

Comment: скрипты все проверил все подключено:
header.php
секция <head>(все типа по учебнику, все проверил, не знаю...)
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/p/jquery_plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
<script src="/p/jquery_plugins/position/jquery.backgroundPosition.js"></script> 
<script src="/p/myPoll/poll.js" ></script>

в загруженной странице в ресурсах все скрипты на месте

Comment: проверьте тогда все пути к файлам, xxx.html грузиться из папки p/myPoll/xxx.html, а куда тогда смотрит define('HTML_FILE', 'xxx.html')

Comment: @makregistr я изменил на /p/myPoll/xxx.html
но результата это не повлияло на результат никак

Answer (score 1):

Хе-хе, аяксом-то вы голосование подгрузили, а скрипты, которые с ним идут, забыли. В итоге, poll.js не работает, а с ним не работает и плавная отправка формы. Грузите его на главной странице, до подгрузки формы голосования.

Comment: да не. все прописано, вот, в заголовке, и джейквере там же: 
<script src="/p/myPoll/poll.js" ></script>
в этой папке тоже все лежит на месте

Comment: В poll.js событие отправки формы повешено на submit(...) или live('submit', ...) ?

Comment: @ling видимо на первое

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#poll").submit(formProcess); // setup the submit handler
  
  if ($("#poll-results").length > 0 ) {
    animateResults();
  }
  
  if ($.cookie('vote_id')) {
    $("#poll-container").empty();
    votedID = $.cookie('vote_id');
    $.getJSON("/p/myPoll/poll.php?vote=none",loadResults);
  }
});

Comment: я изминил:
$("#poll").submit(formProcess);
на:
$("#poll").live('submit', formProcess);

--не работает, я может не верно, что то сделал?

Answer (score 1):

вобщем то выяснилось, что в некоторых ситуациях кнопка сабмит перестает работать(в ае 67 стопудово), но от чего то кнопка не работает и у меня в хроме, так что можно эту кнопку заменить на

```
<a href="#" onClick="submitFun(); return false;">Vote ----></a>
```

а на функцию повесить

```
$("#poll a").click(function() {
        $(this).parents().filter("form").trigger("submit");
    });
```

переписал код в шаблон и теперь функция выглядит так:

```
function myPoll_v_1(){

global $user_ID; if ($user_ID) {

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#poll a").click(function() {
        $(this).parents().filter("form").trigger("submit");
    });
        //$('#pollc').load('p/myPoll/xxx.html');
});
</script>
<div id="poll-container">
<div class="trace22">  </div>
<h3>Poll</h3>
<form id="poll" action="/p/myPoll/poll.php" method="post">
<p>Pick your favorite Javascript framework:</p><p>
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt1" id="opt1" /><label for='opt1'>&nbsp;jQuery</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt2" id="opt2" /><label for='opt2'>&nbsp;Ext JS</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt3" id="opt3" /><label for='opt3'>&nbsp;Dojo</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt4" id="opt4" /><label for='opt4'>&nbsp;Prototype</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt5" id="opt5" /><label for='opt5'>&nbsp;YUI</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt6" id="opt6" /><label for='opt6'>&nbsp;mootools</label><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Vote &rarr;" onclick="return false" /></p>
<a href="#" onClick="submitFun(); return false;">Vote ----></a>
</form>
</div>

<?

    }else{
     echo  ' ';

    }

}
```

строчку

```
define('HTML_FILE', 'файл_возврата.хтмл');
```

можно заменить на:

```
define('HTML_FILE', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

в результате, у нас есть форма, в которой можно что то выбрать, и нажимать на vote после чего происходит смена формы на результаты голосования с анимацией, но не происходит самого голосования. будем разбираться дальше.