# Почему не работает часть кода?

Tags: ajax, html, php, javascript

Как бы все бьюсь с голосованием с [этого урока](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=832). Собственно возникло предположение, что, возможно, что-то не работает из-за того, что урок рассчитан на одну версию php, а у меня другая стоит. Возможно ли такое?

Собственно если вкратце, то сейчас просто при выборе варианта и нажатии на кнопку голосования, происходит смена содержимого контейнера, показ результатов голосования, но самое главное **не происходит голосования** (то есть, не записывается результат и айпишник в специальные файлы). Описание того, что есть сейчас.

В одном из нужных мне мест я вызываю функцию:

```
myPoll_v_1();
```

Описание функции (в одном из файлов шаблона):

```
function myPoll_v_1(){
    global $user_ID; if ($user_ID) {//если залогинен, то выполняем
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { //как только все загружено 
    $('#pollc').load('p/my_poll/xxx.html'); //подгружаем форму(это не обходимо так как php файлу надо знать куда возвращать результат)
});
</script>
<div id="pollc">
<!--куда подгружать форму-->
</div>
<?
}else{//если не залогинен выводим пробел
    echo  ' ';
}
}
```

файл формы(xxx.html):

```
<script src="/p/my_poll/poll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><!-- засунул подключение сюда, так как в хедере скрипт не срабатывает--></script>
<div id="poll-container">
<div class="trace22"><!--трассировка--></div>
<h3>Poll</h3>
<form id='poll' action="/p/my_poll/poll.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<p>Pick your favorite Javascript framework:</p><p>
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt1" id="opt1" /><label for='opt1'>&nbsp;jQuery</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt2" id="opt2" /><label for='opt2'>&nbsp;Ext JS</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt3" id="opt3" /><label for='opt3'>&nbsp;Dojo</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt4" id="opt4" /><label for='opt4'>&nbsp;Prototype</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt5" id="opt5" /><label for='opt5'>&nbsp;YUI</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="poll" value="opt6" id="opt6" /><label for='opt6'>&nbsp;mootools</label><br /><br />
<a onclick="return false;">Voooote &rarr;</a><br><!-- это за место поля input type submit который не работает вообще-->

</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Есть там такой файл flatfile.php для работы с файлами, как с базой данных (если я правильно понял) и вот там есть странный кусок, который наводит меня на определенные мысли о несовместимости этого файла с моей версией php, он с комментарием на иностранном языке (а я и русский плохо знаю, лол). Отрывок flatfile.php:

```
function resolveJoins(&$tables)
{
    foreach ($tables as $tablename => $discard) {
        // PHP4 compatible: can't do :  foreach ($tables as $tablename => &$tabledef)
        // and strangely, if we do 
        // foreach ($tables as $tablename => &$tabledef)
        //     $tabledef =& $tables[$tablename];
        // then we get bugs
        $tabledef =& $tables[$tablename];
        foreach ($tabledef as $colname => $discard) {
            $coldef =& $tabledef[$colname]; // PHP4 compatible
            if (is_a($coldef, 'JoinColumn') or is_subclass_of($coldef, 'JoinColumn')){
                TableUtils::resolveColumnJoin($coldef, $tables);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34145) я спрашивал тоже по этой проблеме.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, я слабо шарю в этом, так как дизайнер, и бьюсь уже вроде 3 день. А времени на изучения всех этих технологий нету. Отдам все свои очки, кто особенно хорошо поможет. )

Comment: Если для вас действительно важно решение данно проблемы - пишите в скайп: **alexwindhope**
<br>
Там и разберемся, на пальцах решать такую проблему ущербное занятие :)

Comment: @alexwindhope напиши пожалуйста ответ который ты говорил по скайпу.
вопрос надо закрыть, и обещание выполнить)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка формирующая id категории за которую голосуют инициализировалась так:

```
$id = $_GET['vote'] || $_POST['vote'];
```

Соответственно $id всегда был пуст и соответственно голоса не изменялись, вообщем проблема была в особенности оператора ||, строку выше необходимо было заменить на:

```
$id = $_GET['vote'] or $_POST['vote'];
```

**DemoS** А разница? там код образца 2005 года, задача была чтобы работало а не чтобы код был красивый :) И если на то пошло то лучше всего было бы просто
    if($_GET['poll'])

Да, и проблема вообще не в тех краях была какбы...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

blackjack9000, вы исправили в пхп часть кода? Когда передаются данные обработчику demo/golosovanie/poll.php?vote=1, у меня выскакивали пхп ошибки

```
Notice: Undefined index: poll in E:\demo\golosovanie\poll.php on line 24
```

я исправил эту строчку в poll.php

```
if ($_GET['poll'] || $_POST['poll']) {
```

на

```
if (isset($_GET['poll']) || isset($_POST['poll'])) {
```

на сервере выставляете права файлам, чтобы они были доступны на чтение и запись и смотрите.

Comment: права вроде выставлены. таких ошибок у меня не выскакивало была ошибка в 128 вроде строке при не верном пути к файлу ответа

Answer (score 1):

А еще лучше вместо

```
if (isset($_GET['poll']) || isset($_POST['poll'])) {
```

Писать

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['poll'])) {
```

Comment: пока все работает, пока трогать не буду.

Comment: разница в том, чтобы уменьшить код.
массив $_REQUEST, содержит в себе $_GET, $_POST и $_COOKIE массивы.